# Edit query profile output in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I imported Dbpedia in Virtuoso and have a few thousand queries, with which I want to build a dataset. I've read about [`prof_enable`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_prof_enable/) and see of course the output it creates with `virtprof.out`. But is there a way to edit this file? 
e.g. it shortens the query, which I don't want.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use `prof_enable` to, somehow, build a data subset of DBpedia? This doesn't make sense to me. What is your actual goal? The more detail you can provide, [the clearer you can make your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the better any of us can help...

Comment: Ah yes - wording is confusing.. :) I have dbpedia on virtuoso and want to run some usewod queries on it. With those usewod-queries + execution times (+more later) I want to build a database. hope this makes it clearer ;)

Comment: it's probably more of a super-user type question, than a stackoverflow..